# Wat is the optimal Azure REDIS Stackexchange configuration and usage running a .NET Core 2.1 WebApi

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm running a .NET Core 2.1 web api on Azure App Services on two P3V2 instances. Connected to a Azure REDIS service Premium P1 using the StackExchange Redis client.

Currently our peak load is about 7000 web requests a second. Resulting in a REDIS load of 2,5MB/sec and at max a cache-hit value of 400k a minute (Azure Metrics).

Lately I'm having connection issues and so I'm investigating all available documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html

> No connection is available to service this operation: GET languages;
>   It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout
>   One or more errors occurred. (It was not possible to connect to the
>   redis server(s); ConnectTimeout) (It was not possible to connect to
>   the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout) It was not possible to connect to
>   the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout It was not possible to connect to
>   the redis server(s);    ConnectTimeout
>
> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException:    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed
>   (StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullStackExchange.Redis, Version=1.2.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.csStackExchange.Redis,
>   Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 2000)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Infrastructure.Caching.CacheService+d__8`1.MoveNext

After restarting the web-application the problem is solved. Within Application Insights and looking at the failed requests, I can't clearly see if it is only one api-instance or on all instances. But looking at the client-apps, we think it is just one instance.

My implementation is as follows:

```
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => LazyConnection.Value;

    protected override IDatabase Cache => Connection.GetDatabase();

    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
        new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            var configurationOptions = CreateConfigurationOptions();
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
        });

    protected static ConfigurationOptions CreateConfigurationOptions()
    {
        var deltaBackOffInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Milliseconds;
        var maxDeltaBackOffInMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Milliseconds;

        var config = new ConfigurationOptions();

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-redis-cache-retry-guidelines
        config.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        config.ConnectRetry = 3;
        config.ConnectTimeout = _redisConfiguration.ConnectionTimeoutInMs;
        config.ReconnectRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(deltaBackOffInMilliseconds, maxDeltaBackOffInMilliseconds);

        config.EndPoints.Add(_redisConfiguration.HostName);
        config.Password = _redisConfiguration.Password;
        config.Ssl = _redisConfiguration.Ssl;
        config.DefaultDatabase = _redisConfiguration.DatabaseId;

        return config;
    }
```

**Question 1: async connection**

My web api is fully async (from the controllers until SQL and REDIS). Is it then also recommended to implement the ConnectAsync method from the ConnectionMultiplexer?

**Question 2: Custom Forced Reconnect (answered)**

Due to some SE.Redis issues reported at https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues and downgrading back to 1.2.6 should help, I also downgraded to this version. But it didn't resolve my connection issues.

I stumbled upon this code-sample from Jon Cole:
https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-lazyreconnect-cs
I'm about to implement this in combination with the current SE.Redis 1.2.6 version. But I'm having doubts, is this still necessary when updating (back) to the latest SE.Redis version?

**EDIT:** Jon Cole responded with an answer. You might still want to add this ForceReconnect whenever you encounter connection issues. Independent of the SE.Redis version you are using. Source: https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#gistcomment-3025550

Because network-blips or -drops are very hard to debug or to reproduce (local or on a staging environment) with the same load I'm kind of forced to test-in-production.